# Python dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I am just starting to learn how to program and have a function that I need to write in Python, this is the idea behind it:

It returns `True` if `word` is in the `wordList` and is entirely composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns `False`. Does not mutate hand or wordList.

There is a function to call that checks the frequency of the letters in the word the user comes up with and that is a converted to a dict, I have tried using iteritems various ways but to no avail, I am getting stuck on the words that have repeated letters, they are being returned as true when I don't have two entries for that letter in the users hand.

Sorry if this is unclear I only started two weeks ago.
any pointers would be great I have been stuck on this for a long time!

```
def isValidWord(hand,word,wordList):

    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely

    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """

    wordC = getFrequencyDict(word)
    handC = dict.copy(hand)
    if word not in wordList:
        return False
    for c in word:
        if c not in hand:
            return False
        for k,v in wordC.iteritems():
            if k in hand and v > 1:
                 handC[k] -= 1
```

basically my next step was trying to figure out how to compare word to handC with amended value and discounting any key with a value of zero.
I think(hope) that will work.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: If you feel like you're not coming through with a clear explanation of your problem, it's often very helpful to post the code you've come up with, as it usually clears up what your intentions are and where you're having trouble. It also helps people see that you've at least tried something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code, let me see if I understand what you want: you're trying to see if the given word can be spelled using the letters in `hand` as if the user had a Scrabble tile for each letter in `hand`, yes?

Personally I'd just copy the `hand` dictionary and then allow changes to the copy. Something like this:

```
def is_valid_word(hand, word, wordlist):
    hand_cp = dict(hand)
    for letter in word:
        if hand_cp.get(letter):
            # The letter is in our hand, so "use it up".
            hand_cp[letter] = hand_cp[letter] - 1
        else:
            # The letter isn't in our hand, so the word isn't valid.
            return False

    # If we can make the word, now make sure it's a real word:
    # (If wordlist is long, you might want to sort it and do a real search)
    if word not in wordlist: 
        return False

    # We haven't found any reason to return False, so this is a valid word.
    return True
```

Comment: just had to change hand.get to hand_cp.get and hand[letter] to hand_cp[letter] and it worked perfectly!!!. Thanks a lot ,much appreciated I was banging my head against the wall for last few hours.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Whoops! Glad I could help (and fixed for posterity).

Comment: @ Henry, how do I mark as solved or what is the procedure here?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There should be a check mark to the left of the answer (near the up/down arrows); if you click it it'll turn green and mark the answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
def isValidWord(hand, word, word_list):
    if word not in word_list:
        return False
    for c in word:
        if c not in hand:
            return False
    return True
```

As strings are iterable you can check character by character.

Good luck

Comment: the words with repeated letters failed the test, that was first thing I tried, python basically seeing abc equal to abcc.Thanks for trying!

Comment: @Padraic Sorry to hear that, I didn't understand what you meant. In my defense it does, however, answer to this definition: _It returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False. Does not mutate hand or wordList._ Perhaps you could be clearer on what you need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

The python `Counter` class is your friend. You can do this in [python 2.7 and later](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def is_valid_word(hand, word, word_list):
    letter_leftover = Counter(hand)
    letter_leftover.subtract(Counter(word))
    return word in word_list and all(v >= 0 for v in letter_leftover.values())
```

Then:

```
>>> def test():
...     hand = "traipse"
...     word_list = ["all", "the", "words", "in", "English", 
                     "parts", "pines", "partiers"]
...     print is_valid_word(hand, "parts", word_list)
...     print is_valid_word(hand, "pines", word_list)
...     print is_valid_word(hand, "partiers", word_list)
... 
>>> test()
True
False
False
```

Comment: Thank you , very interesting, I think I need to learn a bit more about Counter!!

Answer (score 0):

here is mine

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """
    if word in wordList:
        if set(word).issubset(set(hand)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```